# C++ Keeping count when global variable is not appropriate

Tags: c++, global-variables, forward-declaration

I need to coordinate & issue a unique sequential numeric identifier (1, 2, 3... etc) to object instances stemming from a particular GrandParent object.

I am creating a C++ DLL using a Microsoft compiler and where all variables are encapsulated inside objects; global variables are not an option in this case and are in fact being engineered away in this project.

I have tried in the following way to solve the problem and have discovered that it is not possible through forward declaration to access another object's member function (N.B. code to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, it will not compile due to incorrect use of forward declaration to access a member function):

GrandParent class:

```
//GrandParent
class GrandParent
{
public GrandParent(){}

int addParent()
{
Parent *par = new Parent(this);
return 0;
}

int incrementGrandChildIDNumber()
{
return grandChildIDNumber +=1;//increment
}

private:
int grandChildIdNumber;//keep count.  This NEEDS to be encapsulated. Cannot be a
 //global variable as there will be multiple instances of GrandParent each counting
 //and labeling it's own grand children.
};
```

Parent class:

```
//Parent
class GrandParent;//forward declaration
class Parent
{
public Parent(GrandParent *ptrToGrandParent): ptr2GP(ptrToGrandParent){}

addGrandChild()
{
id = ptr2GP->incrementGrandChildIDNumber();//but forward declaration does not
    //give access to GrandParent member functions, right??
GrandChild grndChld = new GrandChild(id);
return 0;
}

private:
int id;
GrandParent *ptr2GP;
};
```

GrandChild class:

```
//GrandChild
 class GrandChild
{
 public:
    GrandChild(const int &id):idNumber(id){}

 private:
int idNumber;
};
```

I have simplified the problem, in reality each class is much longer and defined in its own header file.

My question is: if forward declaration does not work and global variables are NOT appropriate in this project what other options are available to coordinate the issuance of ID numbers to GrandChild objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate class definitions and declarations in different files and use static variables:

```
// GrandParent.hh
#ifndef _GrandParent_
#define _GrandParent_

class Parent;

class GrandParent
{
  public:
    GrandParent();

    Parent * addParent();

    int incrementGrandChildIDNumber();

  private:
    static int grandChildIdNumber;
};

#endif


// GrandParent.cpp
#include "GrandParent.hh"
#include "Parent.hh"

int GrandParent::grandChildIdNumber = 0;

GrandParent::GrandParent()
{
}

Parent * GrandParent::addParent()
{
  Parent * par = new Parent(this);
  return par;
}

int GrandParent::incrementGrandChildIDNumber()
{
  return grandChildIdNumber++;
}

// Parent.hh
#ifndef _Parent_hh_
#define _Parent_hh_

class GrandParent;//forward declaration
class GrandChild;

class Parent
{
  public:
    Parent(GrandParent *ptrToGrandParent);

    GrandChild * addGrandChild();

  private:
    int id;
    GrandParent * ptr2GP;
};
#endif

// Parent.cpp
#include "Parent.hh"

#include "GrandParent.hh"
#include "GrandChild.hh"

Parent::Parent(GrandParent * ptrToGrandParent) : 
  ptr2GP(ptrToGrandParent)
{
}

GrandChild * Parent::addGrandChild()
{
  id = ptr2GP->incrementGrandChildIDNumber();
  GrandChild * grndChld = new GrandChild(id);
  return grndChld;
}


// GrandChild.hh
#ifndef _GrandChild_hh_
#define _GrandChild_hh_

class GrandChild
{
  public:
    GrandChild(int id);

  private:
    int idNumber;
};

#endif

// GrandChild.cpp
#include "GrandChild.hh"

GrandChild::GrandChild(int id) : 
  idNumber(id)
{
}
```

And use them from main:

```
#include "GrandParent.hh"
#include "Parent.hh"
#include "GrandChild.hh"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  GrandParent grandPa;

  Parent * parent1 = grandPa.addParent();
  Parent * parent2 = grandPa.addParent();

  GrandChild * gChild1_1 = parent1->addGrandChild();
  GrandChild * gChild1_2 = parent1->addGrandChild();

  GrandChild * gChild2_1 = parent2->addGrandChild();
  GrandChild * gChild2_2 = parent2->addGrandChild();
}
```

Comment: When applied in reality there will be multiple GrandParent instances and so they would all be refering to the *same* static variable?  Am I right? I need each GrandParent to keep a unique count, not including GrandChildren from other GrandParents.

Comment: So, change `GrandParent::grandChildIdNumber` to a non static variable but do not forget to initialize on GrandParent constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a singleton class which has a function to generate a unique identifier.  (This can be sequential based on a counter, or based on any other scheme you like.)

Alternatively, this can just be a function in the base class which returns a unique id based on a static counter.  You can even put it in the base class constructor.

Comment: How would a singleton allow one of multiple instances of GrandParent to keep a unique count of its GrandChildren and also allow Parent objects to obtain an incrementation of the count when creating a new Grandchild?

Comment: Aha, you're right, sorry I misunderstood your question; I thought you wanted a single counter that is shared by all instances.  In that case your code is fine, just get it to compile by separating the class implementations and declarations.  Basically, Tio Pepe's answer.